# Add DynamicResource to Template of a control in code...C#

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF application, I have a ControlTemplate in my resources inside of a user control:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="RadioButtonControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
          <ToggleButton Margin="4" Checked="ToggleButton_Checked" Unchecked="ToggleButton_Unchecked" Content="{Binding Content, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
     </ControlTemplate>
 </UserControl.Resources>
```

I have a StackPanel that will hold some radio buttons. Doing it in xaml like so:

```
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" />
            </StackPanel.Resources>
                    <RadioButton GroupName="Group1" Content="A" Template="{DynamicResource RadioButtonControlTemplate}"/>
                    <RadioButton GroupName="Group1" Content="B" Template="{DynamicResource RadioButtonControlTemplate}"/>
                </StackPanel>
```

But my items in the StackPanel will come from a data source meaning they're going to be dynamic.
I can create the radio buttons and add them to my panel fine, I don't know how to add the template to each button in c#:

```
        var rb = new RadioButton();
        rb.GroupName = "Group1";
        rb.Content = "A";
        //rb.Template = ???????;
        clientStackPanel.Children.Add(rb);
```

How do I add DynamicResource RadioButtonControlTemplate to my radio buttons in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `rb.SetResourceReference` method. A resource reference is similar to the use of a `DynamicResource` in xaml.

```
rb.SetResourceReference(RadioButton.TemplateProperty, "RadioButtonControlTemplate");
```